# I have installed @react-native-community/async-storage but there is an error importing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am working with react-native and I have installed `@react-native-community/async-storage` using the command: `npm add @react-native-community/async-storage` and it showed no errors. Now, I am trying to import the library in the server's file using the command: `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';` and I am getting an error saying:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```